# increment an integer in a array_walk() in PHP

Tags: php, array-walk

I need to use an incremented value for the index `orders2` of the array and I have tried the following:

```
$i = 0;
array_walk($arr1, function(&$a) {
  $i++;
  $a['orders2'] = $i;
});
```

Which says `$i` is unknown in the line `$i++;`.

I know I can use `foreach()` but I want to know if `array_walk()` has the bahavior of a regular loop. Any comments would be appreciated!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`$i` is not inside the scope of your anonymous function. You'll have to tell the function to import it:

```
$i = 0;
array_walk($arr1, function(&$a) use (&$i) {
  $i++;
  $a['orders2'] = $i;
});
```

You'll need to import it as a reference, because otherwise it will create a copy of `$i` instead of modifying the outer variable.